# Degree of bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I have a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) whose sets of nodes have $N_1$ and $N_2$ nodes respectively.

What is the average degree of the two sets ($\bar{k_1}$ and $\bar{k_2})$?

I know that:
$$\bar{k}=\frac{2L}{N_1+N_2}$$
where $L$ is the number of links of the network.

Is there an expression connecting $N_1$, $N_2$, $\bar{k_1}$ and $\bar{k_2}$?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the vertex classes $S_1$ and $S_2$ and call their degree sums $s_1$ and $s_2$. As the graph is bipartite, each edge  connects a vertex in $S_1$ to a vertex in $S_2$. So $s_1 = s_2 = L$.

As $\bar{k}_1 = s_1/N_1$ and $\bar{k}_2 = s_2/N_2$, this gives $N_1 \bar{k}_1 = N_2 \bar{k}_2$.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand why _"As the sum of the degrees of a set of vertices is equal to the product of the average degree and the number of vertices in the set.."_

Comment: As average = sum / number, rearranging gives sum = average * number

Comment: I edited the main message. I know that it is a easy thing, but I can't understand.

Comment: I have edited my answer - is it clearer now?

Comment: Thanks, you've been very kind!

Comment: No problem :) You should remove the edit to the question asking for clarification